# ireport not working after making executable

Tags: java

I am developing a point of sales system in java using ireport as my reporting tool, which works fine in the IDE (Netbeans), but after packaging with install anywhere the ireport does not work anymore. Can anyone help on which library I might have excluded. Or where I am mistaken

Comment: Did you add iReport jar files into build path? Try running your jar file with cmd to see which exception has occurred. Than Post here

Comment: i did add the jar file in the build path, when i run on cmd it complain about my database connection class not anything about jasper report. um just stuck please help

Comment: Which DB are you using? and did you add jdbc driver in build path? also add dependencies in deployment assembly

Comment: um using mysql i thank i must make it clear that um new in java programming. I added mysql connector in the libraries of my project. by build path you mean lib folder in the JDK? i do not know the deployment assembly, can just explain it so that i try it. um using netbeans IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Your executable jar file not working because it can't find its dependent jar file any more in the packaging. You can also get the exact exception by running application by cmd. like:
cmd -> open directory which contain your jar file -> write **jarfile.jar**
You have to do following steps:

1. open properties of your project
2. click on build => packaging
3. than you must check on copy dependent liraries
4. output package will pack your project in jar file and libraries in lib folder
5. you must move your lib folder as well if your moving your jar file

[image]

Comment: i did everything  you said i should do but still things dont work out, i downloaded jasper report library and included all the jar files in its lib folders to test if i have left some dependencies by mistake but still the report does not show up after packaging.

Comment: does lib folder contain all dependent jar-files?

Answer (score 0):

I've made a temporary solution to this problem about iReport/jasper report not opening/making an executable.

Seems that the program cannot locate the .jrxml/.jasper file in its default location (within the project folder usually with the build and manifest file) so the alternative would be to save the report file somewhere in the hard disk. ex. "D:/Files and Documents/Documents/report1.jrxml"

This works but somehow not the proper way.

Comment: Maybe you can clarify how it's "not the proper way"?

Comment: what i meant was most programmers would want to do this using a relative path. if the file you're linking to is in the same directory. However i cant figure out why it doesn't work on an executable. so i decided to use an absolute path which would be a problem if i decided to use this on another computer.

Answer (score 0):

1. After you design your report in jrxml, then compile it
   [(click that icon)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpOPk.jpg).
2. then change your **jrxml** report to **jasper**, like this.

   ```
   Map<String, Object> nim = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   nim.clear();
   Statement stmt2 = SGB.c.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs = stmt2.executeQuery("select * from mytable;");
   JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("report.jasper", nim, new JRResultSetDataSource(rs)); 
   JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint);

   formReport fformReport = new formReport(mainform,true);
   fformReport.setBounds(jv.getBounds());
   fformReport.getContentPane().add(jv.getContentPane());
   fformReport.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   fformReport.setVisible(true);
   ```